# Day and Night time categorizing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried many commands to get the day night time correctly as I defined it in the dictionaries. However, it works partly and return other unexpected results.

I have the following dataframe and commands

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'date': ['2010-01-01 12:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:33', 
'2010-04-02 12:01:00', '2010-04-01 07:24:00', '2011-01-01 00:01:00', 
'2011-01-01 01:27:33', '2013-01-01 12:51:00', '2014-01-01 00:30:00', 
'2014-01-01 13:27:33', '2015-01-01 15:27:33', '2016-01-01 14:32:04', 
'2011-01-01 21:28:00', '2015-01-01 22:27:33', '2015-01-01 15:45:00', '2015-01-01 23:27:43', 
              '2015-01-01 23:57:53']})
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], errors='coerce')
data['time'] = data['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], errors='coerce')
data['time'] = data['time'].dt.time

day = {'d': "'5:30:00'", 'n': "'21:30:00'"}
druing_day = {'morning': '4:30:00', 'afternoon': '11:00:00', 'evening': '16:30','night_time': '21:00:00'}
night = day['n']
day = day['d']
data['d-n'] = data['time'].apply(lambda x: 'day' if x.strftime('%H:%M:%S')<night else 'night')
                                 
morning = druing_day['morning'] # I tried to avoid using these parameters and to pass #druing_day['morning'] directly inside lampda function but it does not recognize it
afternoon = druing_day['afternoon']
evening = druing_day['evening']
night = druing_day['night_time']

data['d_time'] = data['time'].apply(lambda x:'morning' if x.strftime('%H:%M')<afternoon else
                                        'afternoon' if x.strftime('%H:%M')<evening else 'evening' 
                                        if x.strftime('%H:%M')<night else 'night')


data
```

For example: When time is `12:01:00` it returns in column `d-n` the result `night` which is actually day time and in column `d-time` for the time `00:01:00` it returns `morning` but I would like to have it as `night`

The expected reuslts are: [image]

Comment: Have a look at `pd.cut`.

Comment: could you please provide an example on how to use ```pd.cut``` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.indexer_between_time` to check if the index of your dataframe is between a certain timeframe. You only need a `date` column, so no need to make a seperate `time` column if you don't need it for any other purposes.

```
# Set day & nighttime based your specified time frames
data.loc[data.set_index('date').index.indexer_between_time('21:30', '5:30'), 'd-n'] = 'night'
data.loc[data.set_index('date').index.indexer_between_time('5:30', '21:30'), 'd-n'] = 'day'
```

```
# Set time of day based on your specified time frames
data.loc[data.set_index('date').index.indexer_between_time('21:00', '4:30'), 'd_time'] = 'night'
data.loc[data.set_index('date').index.indexer_between_time('4:30', '11:00'), 'd_time'] = 'morning'
data.loc[data.set_index('date').index.indexer_between_time('11:00', '16:30'), 'd_time'] = 'afternoon'
data.loc[data.set_index('date').index.indexer_between_time('16:30', '21:00'), 'd_time'] = 'afternoon'
```

**Result**

```
    ID  date                    time        d-n     d_time
0   1   2010-01-01 12:01:00     12:01:00    day     afternoon
1   1   2010-01-01 01:27:33     01:27:33    night   night
2   1   2010-04-02 12:01:00     12:01:00    day     afternoon
3   1   2010-04-01 07:24:00     07:24:00    day     morning
4   2   2011-01-01 00:01:00     00:01:00    night   night
5   2   2011-01-01 01:27:33     01:27:33    night   night
6   3   2013-01-01 12:51:00     12:51:00    day     afternoon
7   4   2014-01-01 00:30:00     00:30:00    night   night
8   4   2014-01-01 13:27:33     13:27:33    day     afternoon
9   5   2015-01-01 15:27:33     15:27:33    day     afternoon
10  6   2016-01-01 14:32:04     14:32:04    day     afternoon
11  6   2011-01-01 21:28:00     21:28:00    day     night
12  7   2015-01-01 22:27:33     22:27:33    night   night
13  8   2015-01-01 15:45:00     15:45:00    day     afternoon
14  9   2015-01-01 23:27:43     23:27:43    night   night
15  10  2015-01-01 23:57:53     23:57:53    night   night
```